# Why does my -scrollViewWillBeginDragging method of my UIScrollView delegate return such a strange contentOffset value?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiscrollview

PROBLEM SOLVED! STUPID TYPO IN MY CODE!

That's my method of my UIScrollView delegate:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)activeScrollView {
    NSLog(@"contentOffset: %f", activeScrollView.contentOffset);
}
```

Output in console is like:

```
2009-05-06 23:04:45.731 Demo[4851:20b] contentOffset: 21080643979530096233938944.000000
```

for sure my contentOffset isn't so huge ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

contentOffset returns a CGPoint struct, so you'd want to use `activeScrollView.contentOffset.y` instead of trying to pass the entire struct into %f, which is the format specifier for doubles.

Answer (score 2):

Because contentOffset is a CGPoint.

Comment: Thanks! Damn, I really believed I had that .x there!! Thanks for that hint. What a stupid typo!

Answer (score 0):

use NSLog(@"ContenfOffset : %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(activeScrollView.contentOffset));